# Invoke "Find" in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, find, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an application with a `WebView` in it and I used `ActionBarSherlock` to implement the actionbar.

Now when a user long-presses a word in the `WebView` he can then choose to **Find** text and type in whatever he wants to find and use a built in find feature which is great.

Is there any way to invoke that problematically (read: a **find** button that starts the find method without the user having to long-press the `webview`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is simpler, it turns out:

```
public boolean showFindDialog(String text, boolean showIme)
```

It's a built-in method in the WebView controller.
Implemented something like this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int i = item.getItemId();
    if (i == R.id.findInDocument)
    {
        _webMain.showFindDialog(null, true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately though, it's only supported in SDK11+.
This probably means that fragmentation-wise, the suggestion above me is more appropriate where available (although with several modifications, using ABS' built in 'collapsable action' instead of a floating textview).